# why does pysptk error appear and how to correct it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

*I've got this error:*

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysptk'
```

What does this error mean?

I tried installing `pysptk` using `pip` but did not install. I tried to install `pysptk` file from Github that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your python shell

1. `pip install findspark`

   *In Python do:*

   ```
   import findspark
   findspark.init()
   ```
2. *Import the necessary modules:*

   ```
   from pyspark import SparkContext
   from pyspark import SparkConf
   ```

   Done!!!